# Are these packages safe to remove

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 first off. I run apt/apt-get commands and I get the following message.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas bamfdaemon indicator-applet indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-common indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages
  indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound jayatana libaccounts-glib0 libbamf3-2 libfcitx-config4 libfcitx-gclient1 libfcitx-utils0 libgnome-panel0 libido3-0.1-0 libindicator3-7
  liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-settings-daemon1 lightdm python3-psutil ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-greeter unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module
  unity-gtk3-module unity-settings-daemon unity-settings-daemon-schemas
```

Usually I would just run an apt-get autoremove and clear this list, but this one in particular seems like it wants to remove really important stuff. If I uninstall this, will it affect me at all?

For the record I temporarily installed lxde and removed it later along with some other software that came with it. That was 2 days ago, about 4 updates+upgrades and an apt-get autoremove. The list was cleared prior. These are new to the list and I wanna make sure I'm not doing anything stupid.

The only thing I can think of that would trigger this was installing xserver-xorg-video-dummy, but uninstalling that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you do so with `autoremove` and **don't** remove those packages explicitly with `remove package-name`, it should be totally safe.

`autoremove` only removes no longer needed/required dependencies/packages that were installed **automatically**(*i.e by the package management system and not manually by a user*) ... This is clearly stated in [`man apt-get`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> ```
> autoremove (and the auto-remove alias since 1.1)
>   autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed
>   to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed.
> ```

However, the `apt` informative message:

> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

Is merely informative and you don't have to run `autoremove` if you so wish.